# Guardar datos de un csv a una lista en python

Tags: python, csv

tengo un archivo .csv y de este necesito operar con las dos ultimas columnas ( son digitos ) y sin ocupar "pandas" , lo he intentado de varias formas pero no lo logro..

Estos son los datos de mi .csv

> ```
> id     id2     id3    id4
> 1        0    -180    -90
> 2        0    -180  -89.5
> 3        0    -180    -89
> ```

Esto es lo que se me ha ocurrido

```
import pprint;

with open("Test.csv", "r") as f:
    list_lines = f.readlines()   

    for line in list_lines:
       pprint.pprint(line.rstrip('\n').split(','))
```

Comment: ¿Puedes usar el módulo csv de la biblioteca estándar? ¿Que esperas obtener al final?¿Una lista con las dos últimas columnas solo `[[-180, -90],  [-180, -89.5], [-180, -89]]`?

Comment: Al final espero quedarme con las dos ultimas columnas ( solo los datos) para poder operarlos, por eso quiero guardarlos en una lista..
Si, usar modulo csv si

Comment: Es decir, una lista como la que pongo arriba ¿o quieres otra salida?

Comment: Se me ocurre que podria guardar los datos de las dos ultimas columnas en una lista de listas , algo como Lista = [l1[-180,-90],l2[-180,-89.5]]

Comment: Si exacto, una lista como la que has puesto ahí..

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres obtener una lista de las filas con solo las dos últimas columnas tienes varias opciones:

- **Usando el módulo csv:**

  En este caso solo es necesario un slicing de cada fila:

  ```
  import csv


  with open("test.csv", "r", newline='') as f: 
      reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
      next(reader) # Eliminar cabecera
      res = [[float(n) for n in line[-2:]] for line in reader] 

  print(res)
  ```

  Python permite usar índices negativos, en este caso `linea[-2:]` hace que se haga un rebanado de la lista desde el segundo elemento **empezando por el final** hasta el último elemento, es decir, los do últimos elementos de la lista.
- **Sin módulo csv:**

  En este caso la idea es la misma más o menos, pero haremos uso de `str.rsplit`:

  ```
  with open("test.csv", "r", newline='') as f: 
      next(f) # Eliminar cabecera
      res = [[float(n) for n in line.rstrip().rsplit(",", maxsplit=2)[-2:]] for line in f]

  print(res)
  ```

El resultado en cualquier caso es:

> ```
> [[-180.0, -90.0],
>  [-180.0, -89.5],
>  [-180.0, -89.0]]
> ```

Se debe evitar usar `readlines` a no ser que se necesite si o si una lista completa con todas las líneas del csv, por ejemplo cuando se necesita ordenar las filas. La razón es que esto carga al completo el fichero en memoria, lo cuales ineficiente y en muchos casos totalmente innecesario.

### Edición

Para obtener cada valor de cada fila lo más eficiente es iterar sobre la lista de listas con un `for in`:

```
import csv


with open("test.csv", "r", newline='') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    next(reader) # Eliminar cabecera
    res = [[float(n) for n in line[-2:]] for line in reader] 

for a, b in res:
    print(a, b)
```

Se puede usar indexado, pero es más ineficiente y no es la forma "pithónica" de hacerlo:

```
for i in range(len(res)):
    a = res[i][0]
    b = res[i][1]
    # O directamente a, b = res[i]
    print(a, b)
```

Si quieres obtener los valores por separado en el propio for basta con hacer:

```
import csv


with open("test.csv", "r", newline='') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    next(reader) # Eliminar cabecera
    for line in reader: 
        DatoLoP, DatoLap = float(line[-2]), float(line[-1])
        print(DatoLoP, DatoLap)
```

Si quieres cada columna en una lista puedes usar `zip`:

```
import csv

with open("test.csv", "r", newline='') as f: 
    next(f) # Eliminar cabecera
    a, b = zip(*((float(n) for n in line.rstrip().rsplit(",", maxsplit=2)[-2:])
                    for line in f))

print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: Esto me permite operar con cada elemento de las listas por separado? es decir de la lista en la posición [0] tenemos [-180 , - 90] , necesito operar esos dos elementos por separado, estoy intentando imprimir solo ellos y sumarlos con n numero y no lo logro 
"list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple" ese es mi error al operar

Comment: Necesito operar esos numeros aqui :
x1=R*(math.cos(DatoLaP)*math.sin(dl))/(math.sin(DatoLa0)*math.sin(DatoLaP)+math.cos(DatoLa0)*math.cos(DatoLaP)*math.cos(dl))
y aqui :
y1=R*(math.sin(DatoLaP)*math.cos(DatoLa0)-math.cos(DatoLaP)*math.sin(DatoLa0)*math.cos(dl))/(math.sin(DatoLa0)*math.sin(DatoLaP)+math.cos(DatoLa0)*math.cos(DatoLaP)*math.cos(dl))
// Donde DatoLaP seria el primer dato de la lista y DatoLoP son los datos de la lista , digamos  DatoLaP = -180 y DatoLoP = - 90
Los datos R,La0 y Lo0 los asigna el usuario

Comment: Son dos operaciones , obtener x1 y y1 ( con las respectivas operaciones que puse arriba ) donde DatoLap sera en este caso, de la lista [-180.0, -90.0] , obtenemos - 90 como DatoLap..
Si, cada fila debera ser operada de la misma forma

Comment: R , La0 , Lo0 Los puedo pedir al usuario desde el inicio y tenerlos ya, como constantes para operar en la formula que afectara a cada fila de datos que obtenemos del archivo csv

Comment: Lo siento por no ser tan claro , intentare de nuevo.
de: 
x1=R*(math.cos(DatoLaP)*math.sin(dl))/(math.sin(DatoLa0)*math.sin(DatoLaP)+math.cos(DatoLa0)*math.cos(DatoLaP)*math.cos(dl)) y aqui : y1=R*(math.sin(DatoLaP)*math.cos(DatoLa0)-math.cos(DatoLaP)*math.sin(DatoLa0)*math.cos(dl))/(math.sin(DatoLa0)*math.sin(DatoLaP)+math.cos(DatoLa0)*math.cos(DatoLaP)*math.cos(dl))

Comment: DatoLap sera - 90 (Obtenido de la lista  [-180.0, -90.0] que sacamos del archivo csv) De este mismo archivo sacamos mas listas , [-180.0, -89.5] y
 [-180.0, -89.0] y ... que seran operadas de la misma forma
"R" Lo obtenemos del usuario , el lo ingresara una sola vez y quedara constante
"DatoLa0" Lo obtenemos tambien del usuario, lo ingresa una sola vez y quedara como constante
"DatoLo0" al igual que radio y DatoLa0 , lo obtenemos de usuario una sola vez
"DatoLop" lo mencione al inicio pero no existe dentro de mis formulas, lo siento, este lo ignoramos..

Comment: Para obtener los dos elementos por separado como comentaba arriba basta recorrer la lista con un for:  `for DatoLoP, DatoLap in res: x1=R * (math.cos(DatoLaP)....; y1 = R * (math.sin(DatoLaP)...`. También puedes usar indizado: `for linea in res: DatoLoP = linea[0]; DatoLap = linea[1]`.

Comment: Entiendo, ahora el problema es que.. digamos , al llamar a res[0] (para imprimir u operar ) me da un error : unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
Intuyo que es por que, esa posicion es una lista y no un entero, me gustaria tenerlo como entero. 
He intendado acceder a las listas de la lista asi : res[0[0]] pero no lo logro

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices pero no logro aterrizarlo al codigo, lo tengo asi, mira:
with open("test.csv", "r", newline='') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    next(reader) # Eliminar cabecera
    res = [[float(n) for n in line[-2:]] for line in reader]


print(res)
print(res[0][2])
for i in range (0,len(res)):
    x=3+res[i][0]
    z=3+res[0][i]
    print("soy x",x)
    print("soy z",z)
Y sale este error : list index out of range
Se me ocurrio crear ahora dos listas separadas, una para guardar la primer columna y otra la segunda columna con esto (Leer abajo)

Comment: i=0
j=0
LaP=[]

for i in range (0,len(res)-1):
    LaP[j]=res[0][i]
    j+=j
print(Lap)

Comment: Mira he logrado operar con ambas columnas como me dijiste, pero solo una vez dentro del ciclo 
import csv
with open("test.csv", "r", newline='') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    next(reader) # Eliminar cabecera
    res = [[float(n) for n in line[-2:]] for line in reader]

print(res)
i=0
for i in range (0,len(res)-1):
    x=3+res[i][0]
    z=3+res[i][i+1]
    print("soy x",x)
    print("soy z",z)
    i+=i
Despues de iterar una sola vez, me dice list index out of range
Si pudieras ayudarme a guardar una columna por separado en listas separadas seria la bomba

Comment: David he editado la respuesta, mira al final, tienes un poco confuso el tema del indexado en listas, mira a ver si te es de ayuda. `range` no incluye el valor `stop`, es `range(0, len(res))` (a no se que no quieras la última fila). Por otro lado no es `[i][i+1]`, `i` representa el número de línea, las sublistas tienen solo dos elementos, es `[i][1]`,. Por otro lado, si usas un `for` con `range`, no incrementes `i`, `i` ya te la incrementa el `for` .

Answer (score 0):

Si quisieras usar método que no recurra a ninguna librería, puedes hacer algo como:

```
# Cargar el archivo:
list_lines =  open('Test.csv').read().split('\n')

# Realizar transformaciones:
list_lines = map(lambda x:x.split(','),list_lines)
list_lines = map(lambda x:x[2:4],list_lines)
list_lines = filter(lambda x:len(x)>0,list_lines)[1:]
list_lines = map(lambda x:[float(x[0]),float(x[1])],list_lines)
```

En caso de que estés usando python 3.x las últimas dos líneas deberían de ser:

```
list_lines = list(filter(lambda x:len(x)>0,list_lines))[1:]
list_lines = list(map(lambda x:[float(x[0]),float(x[1])],list_lines))
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.